# Populating an empty table with sequential numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table which is already truncated (Microsoft SQL 2008). I have to now populate it with sequential numbers up to `50,000` records arbitrary numbers (doesn't mater) up to 7 characters.

Can any one help as to what SQL statement I need to write that will automatically populate the newly empty table with `A000001`,`A0000002`,`A0000003`, etc so that I can sort number the records within the table.

I have approximately `50000` records which I need to sequentially entered and I really don't want to number the column manually via hand editing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you not just use a number rather than this alphanumeric that you want sorted as a number?  zero padding to accomplish your sort is kind of silly, especially if you ever get to a point where you didn't pad with enough zeros and have to go back.

Comment: Numbers are also fine as long as they a sequential...

Comment: just need to populate a column with any number sequence as long as they are in order

Comment: I would recommend you not put characters in a sequence like this. It is a serious pita to work with and doesn't provide any real benefit. Keep it as a number and just add an identity column. Not matter what you do, you are going to end up with gaps because rows will get deleted at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use excel to generate your unique ids using the following:
In A column:

```
=CONCATENATE($C2, TEXT($B2,"000000"))
```

In B column put a 1 in the first row and the following code in all subsequent rows:

```
=SUM($B4 + 1)
```

In C column:

```
The letter A
```

Then just import the excel csv as a table and you'll have all your ids ready to insert into your empty table.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Stacked CTE` to generate  sequential Numbers

```
;WITH e1(n) AS
(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
), -- 10
e2(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e1 AS b), -- 10*10
e3(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e2 CROSS JOIN e2 AS b), -- 100*100
e4(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e3 CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP 5 n FROM e1) AS b)  -- 5*10000
  SELECT n = 'A'+right('000000'+
  convert(varchar(20),ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n)),7) 
  FROM e4 ORDER BY n;
```

Check *[here](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)* for more methods to generate sequential numbers with performance analysis

Answer (score 0):

The SQL below loads a table variable up. Just select from it and insert the data into the new table. Certainly not the model of efficiency, but it'll get the job done.

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE(
    Value NVARCHAR(10)
)

DECLARE @Counter INT=0
DECLARE @Padding NVARCHAR(20)
WHILE @Counter<50000
    BEGIN
        SET @Counter=@Counter+1

        SET @Padding=
            CASE LEN(CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@Counter))
                WHEN 1 THEN '00000'
                WHEN 2 THEN '0000'
                WHEN 3 THEN '000'
                WHEN 4 THEN '00'
                WHEN 5 THEN '0'
                ELSE ''
            END

        INSERT INTO @tmp SELECT 'A' + @Padding + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@Counter)
    END

select * from @tmp
```

Comment: what if I just want to populate a column instead of a table

Comment: @khan16 Please give a concrete example. You could add an identity column to the table variable, do a ROWNUMBER over on the table to update and join the sets together for the update.

Answer (score 0):

Use a table with an identity column and populate it.  Then update that table to set the alpha value you need as follows:

```
create table MyTable (
    ID int not null identity(1,1),
    Alpha varchar(30)
)

truncate table MyTable

begin tran -- makes it run much faster

declare @i int

select @i = 1

while @i < 1000000

begin

    insert into MyTable (Alpha) values ('')

    select @i = @i + 1

end

commit

update MyTable set Alpha = 'A' + replicate('0', 6 - len(cast(ID as varchar(30)))) + cast(ID as varchar(30))
```